# Add jQuery colorbox plugin to a dynamically created element always show first picture

Tags: jquery, gallery, colorbox

I created dynamically (ajax) pictures table by DataTables.net. Show pictures by colorbox is working good

```
$('.colorbox').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.colorbox').colorbox({open:true});
});
```

html elements are `<a href='/picture.jpg' rel='gallery1' ...`

When I first one click to picture, colorbox always shows first picture in gallery sequence. How I can set / focus to current clicked picture? (When I use **this**, colorbox  shows only one picture).

Thanx

update with example for better illustration:

```
<a href="/image1.jpg">image 1</a>
<a href="/image2.jpg">image 2</a>
<a href="/image3.jpg">image 3</a>

     $('.colorbox').live('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.colorbox').colorbox({open:true}, function() { alert(href:$(this).attr('href')); });
});
```

1) I open web page and click to **image 3** and alert show href **/image1.jpg**

2) then I close colorbox window and click to **image 3** and alert show normally **/image3.jpg**

3) only in the first time, when I show gallery, there is always first picture, bad init?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found :) solving in another thread stackoverflow [Jquery colorbox: initialize gallery on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311868/jquery-colorbox-initialize-gallery-on-click) from **kolypto**

Answer (score 1):

Try this within your click function call

```
$('#elementID').colorbox({width:"100%"}, function(){
$("input:first").focus();
});
```

where input:first should be replaced with the item to be focused.

Cheers

Comment: It isn't working, I updated question for better illustration.